# How can I create a counter that counts down to a given time and date?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xna

I have a given time and date and I want to create a counter in my game that is counting down to this given date. I want to display the counter in this format: Days/Hours/Minutes/Seconds

How can I convert the DateTime {2/3/2020 12:00:00 AM} to something like this: 0 Days / 9 Hours / 30 Minutes / 20 Seconds ?
The counter should run until it has reached the given time {2/3/2020 12:00:00 AM} (0 Days / 0 Hours / 0 Minutes / 0 Seconds).

I get the following date and time from the server but I don't know how to make a counter out of it.

[image: DateTime image]

How can I create a counter that counts down to a given time and date?

```
var NextLeaderboardReset = resultleaderboard.Result.NextReset;
```

Comment: have you **tried** anything yourself so far? for example: taking your target date and *subtracting* the current date?

Comment: If you subtract the current DateTime from the one you are counting down to you'll get a `TimeSpan` that holds the information you want to display.

Comment: I get an error message in this code: DateTime NextLeaderboardReset = resultleaderboard.Result.NextReset; Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) What is wrong with my code?

Comment: please read up on _nullables_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DateTime` minus a `DateTime` will give you a `TimeSpan` object, which is what you want here.  Then you just need to get the correct string format for your countdown:

```
var countDownEnd = new DateTime(2020,2,3);

var timeSpan = DateTime.Now - countDownEnd;

var countDownString = $"Time left: {timeSpan.ToString(@"dd\:h\:m\:s")}";
```